# Installing SSL on Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl

I'm moving my hosting from justhost.com (horrible) to the amazon cloud as it's cheaper, faster, and far more flexible.

My conundrum is that I will need SSL installed in the Amazon cloud. Note - I already purchased an SSL cert from justhost.com (actually through geocerts.com) and have the private key, domain cert and trust cert in my hand.

I have 3 files all downloaded from geocerts.

1) domain.crt :the cert for the domain

2) private.key : my private key

3) issuer.crt : the issuer certificate

Below is my httpd.conf snippet

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.casinobitco.in
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/issuer.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, in testing - the cert doesn't seem proper? It basically looks self-signed, fake, etc. https://ec2-54-232-212-186.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: Did you actually upload those files to the right location on your server and restart Apache?

Comment: @ Michael - Yes, I did

Comment: It certainly doesn't look like it. Please edit your question to show exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Turns out, based on my install, mod_ssl was separate from apache so it was running externally.

What's this mean? I needed to make the virtual host edits in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and NOT httpd.conf.

Hopefully someone will see this thread and it will help them out!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the certificate was issued for the wrong domain name (CNAME). Instead of `www.casinobitco.in` it works only for `ip-172-31-16-43`. In addition, it is indeed self-signed.

Qualys gives the following [test results](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ec2-54-232-212-186.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com&hideResults=on):

> Try these other domain names (extracted from the certificates):
>   **ip-172-31-16-43**
>
> What does this mean?
>
> This web site does not have a properly configured SSL server. We were able to retrieve more than one certificate, but the domain names listed in them do not match the domain name you requested us to inspect (ec2-54-232-212-186.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com). It's possible that:
>
> - The web site does not use SSL, but shares an IP address with some other site that does.
> - The web site no longer exists, yet the domain name still points to the old IP address, where some other site is now hosted.
> - The web site uses a content delivery network (CDN) that does not support SSL.
> - The domain name is an alias for a web site whose main name is different, but the alias was not included in the certificate by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the thought-out response. I originally installed a test certificate to validate I was doing SSL correct, but have updated the files and restarted apache -but it looks like the web is still seeing the self-signed version?